# set an instance of an object's base with a different object instance that has the same base class

Tags: c#, mapping

I apologize in advance - I'm self taught...
Is there an easy way to set all of the properties of a base class to the same properties of a different class that inherits the same base class.  For instance:

```
class Foo : Person
{
}

class Bar : Person
{
}

class Person
{
    string FirstName {get; set;}
    string LastName {get; set;}
    //hundreds more...
}
```

So if I have:

```
var x = new Foo()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    //hundreds more...
};
var y = new Bar();
```

How can I easily map all those properties from x to y without having to specify each property individually?

my idea was something like: y.base = x.base; but that didn't seem to work...

Comment: Are you looking for some OO shortcut or feature? Or do you just want to copy properties. It the latter then [use Automapper](http://automapper.org/). If the former then, no, nothing other than using Reflection to get and set properties.

Comment: You might look into what a copy constructor is/does

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create mapper method
Ex:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public void Copy(Person person)
        {
            this.FirstName = person.FirstName;
            this.LastName = person.LastName;
        }
    }
```

And New Instance with

```
 var x = new Foo()
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
            };
            var y = new Bar();
            y.Copy(x);
```